# How to show different data types in horizontal axis in a Google Sheet Chart

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets

My chart is not showing the label that contains alphabets. But it is showing the labels that have only numbers

All the bars in the charts are showing but the labels for some bars are not showing. This is the screenshot:
[image]

```
//create new chart
var chart = sheet.newChart()
//.setPosition(5, 6, 5, 5)
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
 .setOption('vAxis.title', yTitle)
.setOption('hAxis.title', xTitle)
.setOption("useFirstColumnAsDomain", true)
.addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:A22"))
.addRange(sheet.getRange("L1:S22"))
.setOption("hAxis", {showTextEvery: 1, slantedText: true, viewWindow: 
{max:33}})
.setOption('treatLabelsAsText', true)
.setNumHeaders(1)
.setPosition(5, 6, 5, 5)
.setOption("title", "Battery Chart")
.build()
//.getAs('image/jpeg');
sheet.insertChart(chart)

}
var charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCharts();
```

I want all the labels to be shown

Comment: Could you show an example of the data you're trying to plot on the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at your problem I see what is going on, when you assign the range A1:A22, it is seeing two different types of data, numbers and text. When the axis knows it wants to read numbers (the ones aligned to the right in the column) because they are the first ones to see, it will not recognize the text ones and that results in your problem.

To solve this issue, considering you need the labels with the letters, you can format the entire “A” column to text, you do that by selecting the entire column, then going to format -> number -> plain text, as shown below:

[image]

This will allow the chart to recognize them all as text and it will display all the labels correctly.

Comment: [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490800/set-cell-format-to-text-with-google-apps-script) can help you out with that, they explain how to set the format to plain text in the script.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!